# Selecting columns depending on presence in samples (rows) R

Tags: r, tidyverse, case-when

I have code with lots of count data for different variables like so: (below is simplified - original data set has >100 columns)

```
x y z a b c 

1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 1 
1 1 0 1 0 1
```

And I want to only keep columns where there are at least 3 counts (the variable appears 3 times in samples) ... I tried to do this using
`data%>% adorn_totals("row")`
but this lead to the first column not being included:

```
x     y z a b c 

1     0 1 1 0 0
0     0 1 0 0 1
1     0 1 0 1 1 
0     1 0 1 0 1 
1     0 1 0 1 1 
1     1 0 1 0 1
total 2 4 3 2 5
```

I would like to use tidyverse if possible? Is there a way to use filter() and case_when() to filter data by presence in rows?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Its easier to help you if you include your data as an object : use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. [MRE]

Comment: `df[, colSums(df) >= 3]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Athough shortest answer has already been suggested, this short tidyverse syntax will also do

```
df %>% select(where(~ sum(.) >= 3))

  x z a c
1 1 1 1 0
2 0 1 0 1
3 1 1 0 1
4 0 0 1 1
5 1 1 0 1
6 1 0 1 1
```

Repeating baseR syntax for record

```
df[, colSums(df) >=3]
  x z a c
1 1 1 1 0
2 0 1 0 1
3 1 1 0 1
4 0 0 1 1
5 1 1 0 1
6 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: This is a great answer dear AnilGoyal, concise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you get your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  add_count(variable, wt = value) %>%
  filter(n >= 3) %>%
  select(- n) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id     x     z     a     c
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     0
2     2     0     1     0     1
3     3     1     1     0     1
4     4     0     0     1     1
5     5     1     1     0     1
6     6     1     0     1     1
```